# how is Core-plot supporting portrait to landscape transitions

Tags: ios, core-plot

Have been looking at the latest version of Core-plot ce0fa44812 and the associated example code.
It supports device orientation, however I am unable to determine the mechanism used to provide this support. I see the orientation options provided in the plist.

In particular I am interested in the Real Time plot example, however see no calls to change the bounds upon rotation from portrait to landscape.

So what magic is going on here? There are the bounds being changed.

Answer (score 1):

That version of the *Plot Gallery* example app uses a storyboard with the new iOS 8 split view controller to manage all layout and transitions. The views in each storyboard scene use auto layout to resize automatically when needed.

Comment: I don't suppose there is anywhere I can put a break point to see what is going on?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in `-[CPTLayer layoutSublayers]`, but that will only show you what Core Plot is doing. UIKit takes care of most of it through the storyboard and its view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the frame of hostingView when the device rotate.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:    (id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

} completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    [self.hostingView setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
}];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Then you will change to the landscape plot.

If you want to your device is held in portrait  before you plot the graph. 
You need to set the view controller. Otherwise, there is something like a bug, that the plot is set in portrait size in a landscape mode.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.hostingView setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
}
```